# Sqlite, How to decide whether to execute a WHERE query based on parameters

Tags: sqlite, flutter

```
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryUsers(String gender, int age) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryList = await db.rawQuery('''
      select * 
      from 'user'
      where 
        'user'.gender = '$gender' // if gender(function parameter) is null, do not execute this command
      and 
        'user'.age = $age         // if age(function parameter) is null, do not execute this command
    ''');
    return queryList;
  }
```

How to decide whether to execute a WHERE query based on parameters ? thanks !

Comment: is the input paramter null or is the value in the database null?

Comment: the input paramter is null

Comment: Please don't inject values into a string to be interpreted as SQL.  You are setting yourself up for a bobby-tables attack: https://bobby-tables.com.

Comment: thank you , This is important !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the neatest solution. But you can certainly divide up the
query string and use conditionals to reach a final query string.

```
  var qString =   ''' 
  select * from 'user'
  ''';
 

  if (gender != null && age == null ){
    qString += '''
    where
    'user'.gender = '$gender'
    ''';
  
  } else if (gender == null && age != null ){
        qString += '''
    where
    'user'.age = '$age'
    ''';
  
  } else if (gender != null && age != null) {
    qString += '''where 
        'user'.gender = '$gender' 
         and 
        'user'.age = $age       
    ''';
  } 
  
print(qString);
```